# im using .get() to return the value of the entry box named 'fName' and then print it on the click of the button... but its not working

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

fN = StringVar()
sN = StringVar()
age = StringVar()
yG = StringVar()

Label(root, text="First Name").grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
fName = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=fN ).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(root, text="Surname").grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
sName = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=sN).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(root, text="Age").grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx=4)
age = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=age).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

Label(root, text="Year Group").grid(row=3, sticky=W, padx=4)
yearGruop = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=yG).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

fName_1 = fN.get()
```

> returning the value of the StringVar 'fN' and storing it

```
def print_():
    print (fName_1)
```

> not printing the contents of the first name entry box ##

```
Button(root, text="Create account", command=print_).grid(row=4, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are getting the contents as soon as you started the program thus you are getting empty value.

You need to get the value after clicking the button which means you should put the code that gets value inside of your method.

```
def print_():
    fName_1 = fN.get() 
    print (fName_1)
```

Also, in your code `fName`, `sName` etc. are all set to `None` since `grid()` returns `None`. If you want to use them later you need to use grid on separate line.

```
fName = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=fN )
fName.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)
```

Another point is, you don't need those stringvar values in your code either. You can directly get contents of Entry using get.

```
fName = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=fN )
fName.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

def print_():
    print (fName.get())
```